# Customly change margins for a figure

Tags: floats, margins

Is there a way to customly change the margins only for a figure? Not for the text. I'd like to widen the margins on both sides, left and right, of the page, and keep the figure in the center.

The code I have is the following:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
%\hspace*{-1.5in}
%\makebox[\linewidth]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.41]{result1_mnist_fc_sgd.png}
\includegraphics[scale=0.41]{result2_mnist_conv_sgd.png}
\includegraphics[scale=0.41]{result3_cifar10_sgd.png}
%}
\end{center}
\caption{Results for SGD methods}
\label{fig:NN_example}
\end{figure}
```

I have 3 `\includegraphics` in my figure, the first two I want on one line, with a wider margin, and the third image underneath it.

As can be seen in the code, I've tried `\makebox` and `\hspace`, but both don't work fine. `\hspace` works, but then the image is not centered anymore. `\makebox` puts all images on one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the figure is inserted with `\includegraphics`, use `\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics{myfigure}`. It will overflow equally on both sides, but the caption will be limited to the line width.

You also may use `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{myfigure}`, in order to reduce the size of the figure.

Comment: Thanks! However, this does not work as I like. I namely have 3 \includegraphics in my figure, the first two I want on one line, with a wider margin, and the third image underneath it. I'll post the code in the question to give an idea.

Comment: @Frans just put the first two in the makebox then a blank line then the third.

Comment: Cheers mate! That seems to work!